# What is the title of this superpowers movie?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember watching a SF movie as a kid about 15 years ago about a guy who gains superpowers after he sees a rocket exploding (some red flash if I remember correctly).

One of the superpowers was vision through walls (in one scene he sees circus animals around the corner).

Comment: There was a film with terrence hill (?) that match the description. He was send to a zone to deliver a fine, zone that had been evacuated for a military test. He developped a set of super powers from the explosion. I think the one you described was one of those. His only weakness was that while he was seeing anything red, his powers vanished

Comment: @PATRY - I miss Bud Spencer and Terence Hill movies :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that it's the Italian comedy "Poliziotto superpiù" which was dubbed as ["Super Fuzz"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Fuzz). In the movie, a police officer out in the Florida swamps witnesses the explosion of a test rocket loaded with red plutonium. The radioactive fallout gives him a wide range of super powers. [Here's a trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngvYJtpXkM4) on Youtube.

Comment: Thanks, that was the movie I was looking for. I watched it yesterday. It was a lot funnier when I was 10 years old :)

Comment: @TomislavMuic - Yeah that's always the case with childhood favorites :)