# Superhero who is invincible until he sees the colour red

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for a movie about a superhero who is invincible until he sees the colour red. I watched this film as a child but cannot remember its name or find a record of it anywhere. It would be early 80s I think.

Anyone know what I'm talking about?

Comment: duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37094/what-is-the-title-of-this-superpowers-movie

Answer (score 24):

This sounds like [Super Fuzz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Fuzz), released in 1981

Per wikipedia:

> As time passes, Dave discovers that he has picked up a wide range of super powers, including super reflexes and speed, endurance, telekinesis, precognition, hypnotism, and the ability to survive a window drop from the 23rd story of a building unscathed. **What is more puzzling is that sometimes his powers suddenly fail to work whenever he sees the color red.**

Comment: How long did the main character take to buy/make a set of goggles with a yellow or some other color of tint to them? If the answer is "never", I'm disappointed.

Comment: @Ellesedil - Not as disappointed as I was when I rewatched the movie and it wasn't nearly as funny as I remembered it being :D

Comment: OMG this movie looks amazing, plus it has Terence Hill and Ernest Borgnine... I have to see it!